# How to report RMSE of Lasso using glmnet in R

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, lasso, glmnet, mse

So I'm confused about reporting RMSE (root mean squared error) as a metric of model accuracy when using glmnet.

Specifically, do I report the RMSE of the model itself (i.e., how it performs with the training data used to create it) or do I report the RMSE of the model's performance with new data (aka *test data*)? ...Or both?

I guess I'm also confused as to whether the cross validation performed by the `cv.glmnet` function (see below) is all I need for predicting model accuracy and whether an additional test of the data on a separate tests data set is even necessary? ...

---

Context:

When I run `cv.glmnet`, the cross validation version of the [`glmnet`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf) function in R, it produces a graph showing the MSE (mean squared error) of various iterations of the model given varying values of lambda (the "regularization parameter").

[image: glmnet lambda vs. MSE]

The MSE values are stored under `$cvm`.

Now, I can take the square root of the MSE of any of the CV-iterated models to calculate RMSE.

- In my case, I choose to go with the one standard error rule and choose "lambda.1se" (associated with the dotted line above), producing `sqrt(mod$cvm[mod$lambda == mod$lambda.1se])`.

HOWEVER...

Is this RMSE value even interesting to me?

I assume I should instead report the RMSE of the model when used to predict new values for my test data.

- Is this true?
- If so, is the best way to do this simply to calculate new values using `predict` and then compare them to the actual values from the test data using the following equation?

[image: RMSE equation]

Am I thinking about all this correctly??

---

As a follow up:

How do I approach calculating and reporting RMSE if I lack a test data set and instead have to use cross-validation of my available data?

- Is that cross-validation procedure separate from the one performed in the `cv.glmnet` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Specifically, do I report the RMSE of the model itself (i.e., how it performs with the training data used to create it) or do I report the RMSE of the model's performance with new data (aka *test data*)? ...Or both?

These are called training error and test error, respectively. It's useful to report both, but test error is more important, presuming your interest is in the predictive accuracy of the model. Training error is, in general, an optimistically biased estimate of true error for the entire population, because of overfitting.

> If so, is the best way to do this simply to calculate new values using predict and then compare them to the actual values from the test data using the following equation?

Yes.

> How do I approach calculating and reporting RMSE if I lack a tet data set and instead have to use cross-validation of my availabel data?

Pretty much the same way. The catch is that you also need to use cross-validation to choose the lasso penalty. The way to handle this is to use nested cross-validation—that is, inside each fold of the cross-validation loop, do more cross-validation loops on the training part to choose the lasso penalty.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit confused about the last part of your answer, though. Are you simply describing what `cv.glmnet` does automatically for me? If not, could you help me understand whether the cross-validaiton that occurs in `cv.glmnet` is sufficient to exclude the need to use test data? [in other words: Is the cross-validation procedure you describe separate from the one performed in the cv.glmnet function?]

Comment: @theforestecologist `cv.glmnet` can provide the inner cross-validation loop. You'll need another function for the outer loop, or do it manually.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So a little more R-focused follow-up: Do you have a recommended way of going about that? Should I essentially put `cv.glmnet` inside each fold of the cross-validaiton procedure? If so, how do I extract only the model with the "best" lambda value (i.e., the best "inner loop" CV model) from each "outer" cross-validation loop?

Comment: @theforestecologist Yes. Take `lambda.min` or `lambda.1se` from the return value of `cv.glmnet` and fit another lasso model to all the training data (that the outer cross-validation loop has available on this iteration) with this lambda.